# Can't construct a NumberFormatter

Tags: php, symfony, wamp

I'm still developing a symfony2 application, and when I try to submit an embedded form, I get

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\NumberToLocalizedStringTransformer.php on line 130

Some basic NumberFormatter code :

> $fmt = new NumberFormatter( locale_get_default(), NumberFormatter::DECIMAL );
>
> echo $fmt->format(123.123123);

In fact, I can't even construct a NumberFormatter object despite the fact I've enabled intl.
I am currently working on WAMP 2.2c

Conf :

> PHP 5.3.9
> intl 1.1.0.0

Any idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: I wonder why symfony doesn't signal the flaw earlier. You should show some code.

Comment: Done it, but it really is a NumberFormatter construction problem.

Comment: So the code you've posted gives a fatal error as well?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same. Except for the filename of course..

Comment: and except for the method, obviously. Another funny thing is that it perfectly runs on my Archlinux. I heard somewhere it's a int.dll problem... But how ? When ? Whaat !?

Comment: Could make sense. If the PHP extension is unable to locate the actual intl number formatter library, it can just fail. I wonder it fails in such a way, but you should verfiy if dependencies are matched. Talk back with other users of the WAMP server you're using and provide your short example script with a error description.

Comment: The intl extension seems to be perfectly found and loaded since it's listed in phpconfig(). And if it wasn't, it would send a beautiful 'Class NumberFormatter not found'.

Comment: and my locale_get_default() returns my locale. It also depends on intl.

Comment: What does `locale_get_default()` return? And if the underlying libraries are messed up, then even if the extension successfully loads, it can be broken.

Comment: Your current locale, as a string. In my case "fr_BE". Also tried some more common values (like en_US or en_GB), nothing changed.

Comment: Well, I tried with EasyPHP and AMPPS... When I enable php_intl.dll, they both tell me it's not a valid Win32 application...

Comment: Make a bug report on the wamp site. You might not be the only person who have that issue.

Comment: Solved ! Thank you for your help hakre. And have a nice day !

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer below and accept it later. This is how this site works. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Yes, but I can't yet, I have to wait 8 hours to add a comment to my own thread. So I edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well well well...

After some research, I heard it actually was an ICU dll problem. So I went to their website, download + install. Nothing happened.

So, I just went here : http://windows.php.net/download/ I downloaded the same version I have installed, picked up all the icu*.dll files and put it in wamp/bin/php/php5.3.9/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
$fmt = new \NumberFormatter( locale_get_default(), \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL );
```

or add:

```
use \NumberFormatter as NumberFormatter;
```

Comment: I didn't implement it in symfony, but it already is called like that. Thanks. In fact, my little script shown above has nothing to do with symfony2. But it is with Symfony that I found the "bug".